# PDP per product type

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Is it possible to have few PDP's, so for example based on some Product attribute or Product type display different product details pages? If it's not possible OOTB, can somebody from spartacus team guide how it can be archived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options to achieve it:

1. In Backoffice CMS you can configure different page template per product code (or category code). For example, in the sample data used by the the Spartacus demo site, there are configured 2 different page templates for 2 different PLP pages, based on the category code:

   - https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/category/578
   - https://spartacus-demo.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/electronics-spa/en/USD/category/576
2. Alternatively, you can provide a custom `PageLayoutHandler` in Spartacus to amend the page layout, based on additional informations from services, e.g. checking the product code from service or route. For reference, see the implementation of the OOTB [CartPageLayoutHandler](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/3e1002af16a30bf5833692845c9b48bbece777b7/feature-libs/cart/base/components/cart-page-layout-handler.ts#L15) and [how it's provided](https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/6b22368fc6b2faa6ec90b2266fbc7d3e495917fc/feature-libs/cart/base/components/cart-base-components.module.ts#L37-L42).

Comment: Thanks for details and options. Looks like option one is prefarable for us, as it's a standart way how to orginize view using CMSRestrictions at backend configuration.